# How to get all Existing Categories from a Custom Post Type

Tags: categories

so I'm fairly new to worpdress development and I'm still learning my way through, I tried searching anywhere but I cannot find the answer I'm looking for.

The image below is the All categories from my Custom Post Type named **Jewelry**, How can I display this categories in my website? I tried using `get_categories()` but it doesn't work that way or I'm using it the wrong way

[image]

The code below just returns all categories from my POST not my CUSTOM POST TYPE

```
$categories = get_categories(array(
   'hide_empty' => false,
));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the taxonomy slug of it you can use code below:

```
$tax_slug = 'product_cat';
$cpt_terms = get_term( $tax_slug );
echo '<pre>';
  print_r( $terms );
echo '</pre>';
```

but if you don't know the slug, you can use these method:
**First** click on the taxonomy you want to see its terms. In the URL bar in your browser you find sth like this:

> http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=**product_cat**&post_type=product

you can find taxonomy slug and use it in the above code.

**Second** use code below to find taxonomies of a Post Type:

```
$cpt_tax = get_object_taxonomies( array( 'post_type ) => 'product' );
echo '<pre>';
  print_r( $cpt_tax);
echo '</pre>';
```

Note: In this example I used 'product' as post type slug. if you don't know the slug you can find it by clicking on all posts of your CPT and in the URL bar of your browser you find this:

> http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/edit.php?**post_type=product**